# How to run 2 simulators simultaneously on XCode11?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

How can I run 2 simulators for my app simultaneously? Only seen solutions to XCode9 so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the app on Simulator 1, then Run on Simulator 2 ( this will kill the simulator 1 App )

After that manually launch the app on Simulator 1, Go to Debug / Attach to Process and select your app